# Prevent binding a function more than once

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a recursive retry routine, something like this:

```
Foo.prototype.retry = function(data, cb){

   cb && (cb = cb.bind(this));  // want to bind the cb fn just once

   this.resolutions[x] = (err, val) => {

      if(val === 'foobar'){
        // in this case, we do a retry
        return this.retry(data, cb);
      }

   }:

}
```

as you can see, under certain circumstances, I will retry by calling `this.run` again. But I would like to avoid calling `cb.bind()` more than once. Is there any good way to do that?

=> What I mean, is there a way to somehow check a function is bound to a certain `this` value?

The only good solution I know of is to pass a retry count, like so:

```
 Foo.prototype.retry = function(data, cb){

       if(cb){
         if(!data.__retryCount){
             cb = cb.bind(this);
         }
       }

       this.resolutions[x] = (err, val) => {

          if(val === 'foobar'){
            // we do a retry here
            data.__retryCount = data.__retryCount || 0;
            data.__retryCount++;
            return this.retry(data, cb);
          }

       }:

    }
```

Comment: why the downvote? please explain why you don't like the question

Comment: is `cb ? (cb = cb.bind(this))` valid JS? I didn't know you could do a ternary without an alternate defined

Comment: I meant cb && not cb ?, sorry typo

Comment: Ah okay cool, thanks for the clarification :)

Comment: @dandavis, that's what I was thinking of :) can you add an answer please

Comment: Also what's wrong with your solution?

Comment: @NickZuber nothing wrong with my solution, but I was looking for a solution akin to Dan's checking that a function has already had .bind() called on it.

Comment: for what it's worth, I don't think coercing the function to a string and performing a regex operation on a specific stringified code (that seems like a tentative implementation detail) is a good idea. Plus, depending on how many times you rerun that function, you can experience a performance hit because regex is slow

Comment: @NickZuber yeah I agree re: not relying on stringified representation of function

Comment: However @NickZuber consider, however, that the implementation is the way it is, to prevent binding a function more than once. E.g.: function(){}.bind(this).bind(this).bind(this)...I assume only the first call does anything

Answer (score 4):

You can use a local variable for the bound version so when you call yourself recursively, you pass the original `cb`, not the bound one:

```
Foo.prototype.run = function(data, cb){

   let callback = (cb && cb.bind(this)) || function() {};

   this.resolutions[x] = (err, val) => {
      if(val === 'foobar'){
        // we do a retry here and pass original cb
        return this.run(data, cb);
      }
   };

   // then elsewhere in this function when you want to use the bound one, use callback()
}
```

---

Or, if you really only want to ever bind it once, then you can do that in a wrapper function and call yourself recursively via a sub-function that assumes the callback is already bound:

```
// internal function, assumes callback is already bound
Foo.prototype._run = function(data, cb){
    // cb is already bound here
    this.resolutions[x] = (err, val) => {
        if(val === 'foobar'){
        // we do a retry here
            return this._run(data, cb);
        }
   }

}

// bind the callback and then call our internal function
Foo.prototype.run = function(data, cb){
   let callback = (cb && cb.bind(this)) || function() {};
   return this._run(data, callback);
}
```

Comment: @AlexanderMills - I added another option too.

Comment: The first solution is not optimized because you will keep calling bind, but just not on the same function

Comment: In my case, I am not going to retry more than 3 or 4 times. But in general you wouldn't want to keep calling bind() unnecessarily. So I think your second solution is better. Although my prefered is to pass `this` to a truly private _run function and not put _run on the prototype.

Comment: @AlexanderMills - Does this answer your question?  If so, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the green checkmark to the left of the answer and that will also earn you some reputation points.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a class variable which indicates whether or not the function has been bound:

```js
let Foo = function() {
  this.resolutions = [];
};

Foo.prototype.run = function(data, cb) {
  if (!this.bound) {
    console.log('binding');
    cb && (cb = cb.bind(this));
    this.bound = true;
  }

  this.resolutions[x] = (err, val) => {
    if (val === 'foobar') {
      // we do a retry here
      return this.run(data, cb);
    }
  };
};

console.log('x');
let x = new Foo();
x.run();

console.log('y');
let y = new Foo();
y.run();

console.log('x');
x.run();
```

Comment: won't work in this case, because this is a class with many instances, I need to create a boolean for every class instance.

Comment: @AlexanderMills, that would have been good context to include in your question.

Comment: Then make the variable a property

Comment: Summer, you can see it's Foo.prototype, this is a class, but maybe I could have clarified

Comment: It would work in some cases, but it won't work in my case, but I will upvote, because it would work in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

Since binding obscures the origional plain-text function source code from the Function.toString() method, you can inspect the string version to see if a user-land function has been bound:

```
 if(!/\[native code\]/.test(cb)) cb = cb.bind(this);
```

Note you can't use this approach on already native methods like `console.log` or `window.alert`, but that's probably not an issue for your use-case.

in whole:

```
 Foo.prototype.retry = function(data, cb){
   if(!/\[native code\]/.test(cb)) cb = cb.bind(this); //  bind the cb fn just once
   this.resolutions[x] = (err, val) => {
      if(val === 'foobar'){
        // in this case, we do a retry
        return this.retry(data, cb);
      }
   }
};
```